# Sorting Map<String, List<Object>> using java 8

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

How can I sort the map using the data from a value
Example: `Map<String, List<someObject>>` is my input. I need to sort and get the order in `someObject.getVar2()`

**Example:**

```
class SomeObject{
    String var1;
    String var2;
    String var3;
    // getters and setters
}
```

**INPUT**:

Entry 1:

```
{
Key1 = 123
[
someObject
[
var1=4
var2=5
var3=6
]
]
}
```

Entry 2:

```
{
Key1 = 456
[
someObject
[
var1=2
var2=8
var3=1
]
]
}
```

Entry 3:

```
{
Key1 = 789
[
someObject
[
var1=1
var2=2
var3=3
]
]
}
```

OUTPUT after sorting according to var2:

Entry 1:

```
{
Key1 = 789
[
someObject
[
var1=1
var2=2
var3=3
]
]
}
```

Entry 2:

```
{
Key1 = 123
[
someObject
[
var1=4
var2=5
var3=6
]
]
}
```

Entry 3:

```
{
Key1 = 456
[
someObject
[
var1=2
var2=8
var3=1
]
]
}
```

There are 3 entries in Map with format `Map<String, List<someObject>>`
I need to sort this Map collection with var2 values

Before keys are in: 123,456,789

After sorting keys are in: 789,123,456

Comment: Map<String, List<someObject>> *

Comment: it is string with numerical value

Comment: Sample data: {123=[someObject [var1="1", var2="1", var3="2", var4="3", var5="4", var6="5", var7=true]]} .......... 123 is key in String datatype ... someObject is value with different variables in String which I can type caste to numerical value

Comment: please read my comment, add the code or example in post, what is the input, and what should be the output

Comment: are you trying to sort the map by the list entries or sort the lists?

Comment: I updated my post..please look into it.. I am trying to sort the Map according to entryValue which is object type

Comment: @PriyankaAnjuri If you really have a `List<SomeObject>` could you please update the question with the sample input such that there is a list in values and how would then your output look like.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible. Looking at the [documentation of the `Map` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) reveals that

> [...]  Some map implementations, like the `TreeMap` class, make specific guarantees as to their order; others, like the `HashMap` class, do not. [...]

Answer (score 0):

Your input doesn't really fit in the data structure you've used, i.e. `Map<String, List<SomeObject>>`. Since there is never a `List` there in the values (and if there be, the logic for sorting would have to be redefined.) Hence you could simply represent your current input as a `Map<String, SomeObject>`:

```
Map<String, SomeObject> input = new HashMap<>(); // initialised with your sample
```

and then sort it as:

```
Map<String, SomeObject> output = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getValue().getVar2())) // **
    .collect(Collectors
        .toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

** do note that representing `Number`s(mostly `Integer`s here) and then sorting based on them is not probably one should desire.